# The label closing tag (</label>) gets written to my .aspx page when saving the page from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an .aspx page in a web application we have been using for years which was developed and is maintained in Visual Studio 2010. Lately, when I save the page in Visual Studio 2010, it writes a label closing tag (`</label>`) with the green squiggle underline warning:

> "This end tag has no matching start tag."

It always writes it after the `</div>` tag and before the `</fieldset>` tag.

```
        </div>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

I delete the phantom closing tag and as soon as I save the page again, the label closing tag keeps reappearing.

I have spent a few hours researching this on the web and I have found no relevant information regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance for any insight on this peculiar issue.

Comment: Can you provide the full block of HTML? My suspicion is it is doing adding it for you but your tag order is mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

I made some minor updates while reviewing all the code in this page to see what
may be causing the phantom label closing tag (`</label>`). After making these innocuous
changes (changing some indentation to match the rest of the code and deleting one empty div tag (`<div class="container"></div>`), the problem simply went away.

This was truly a mystery.